# Uncompressed Cache images

Tags: cache, media-images

I have a magento store. i did a pagespeed test using "Google PageSpeed Insights" for my home page. In the recommendation google gave me some come cache images to compress. But sonassi image compression script is already running on the base images. so i think that if the base images are compressed there cache versions should also be compressed ...

Can anyone suggest me some solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: do you want to uncompress their cache version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the source images are optimized, and Magento strips the metadata from the cached images when saving them, the cached images can still be not optimal from Google's perspeective. What Google wants also is the quality no more then 85% for JPEG images. I can be mistaken with the number.

The easiest solution is to create an extra scheduled script that will look for new images in the cache location daily and run jpegoptim/pngquant on them.

Here is an article from Byte.nl https://www.byte.nl/blog/image-optimization-using-cronjobs

Here is a question on StackOVerlfow with answer how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38965283/2547265

Answer (score 1):

if your server using apache, just add this to your httacess on the folder root magento project

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 15 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 months"
</IfModule>
```

and if you're using nginx server add this code, on your nginx server config file

```
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
```

hope this helps.